# UIViewController persistence - save state into memory and write it to the disk when the app is terminated

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, state-saving

I am using NSCoding to save and restore my view controllers. However I'm saving to disk the navigation stack + view controllers every time a view controller is pushed or popped.

This is not energy efficient, and there's a better way.

Think of `NSUserDefaults`. It saves the changes somewhere in memory (and if called repeatedly as it is, just overwrite) and when the `synchronize` method is called it writes them to disk. This is genuinely done, and is super energy efficient.

So can I implement something like this? On every call to save changes somewhere in memory and when a `synchronize/writeToDisk` method is called to purge the memory cache and write them to disk.
Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

My idea is to use `NSCache`, and in `application:willResignActive` or `application:willTerminate` to get the object in the cache and write it do disk.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can I ask why you are doing this? Wouldn't it be much less memory/processing to save the datamodel the drives the view controllers, instead of the viewcontroller stack itself? That way you can just recreate it/them instead of serializing the entire controller stack.

Comment: Interesting option ahead, buddy. By using NSCoding is the easiest option I found, but this is pretty interesting. I'll try using your approach. Any ideas on caching this data model?

Comment: `NSCoding` is likely what you'll want. Basically make it so that you can (de)serialize your objects and then use `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];` and `[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:obj toFile:path]`